# Find files with same name but different extensions, send to tgz

Tags: find, tar, recursive

I have a large archive of edited images from my camera, each image is actually a pair of files - *.nef & *.xmp. I would like to go through all the folders and then zip these pairs into single tgz files.

Each of the filenames in a directory is unique, so it would be sufficient to move the file names from output of `ls *.nef` to the command `tar -czf {filename}.tgz {filename}.*`, but I'm afraid I've no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to take care when thinking of Linux and Unix filenames: they do not have "extensions" except by convention.

Comment: OK, that comment isn't helpful. You need to take care when thinking of Linux and Unix filenames: they do not have "extensions" except by convention. That is, "file.nef" and "file.xmp" have different filenames. The ".nef" and ".xmp" are parts of the filenames, not separate fields kept apart from the file name proper, like in FAT filesystems, or ODS-11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short script, xfun:

```
#!/bin/bash
b=$(basename "$1" .xmp)
# echo "tar -cjf $b.tar.bz2 $b.xmp $b.nef"
tar -cjf "$b.tar.bz2" -- "$b.xmp" "$b.nef"
```

Invocation:

```
find -name "*xmp" -execdir ./xfun {} ";"
```

Comment: works on my linux box, but my nas doesn't have find - are there alternatives?

Comment: in a flat directory - if you don't want to visit subdirectories: `for f in *.xmp; do ./xfun "$f"; done`

Comment: Quickly riding this question: I have a similar problem as the OP, but not all .xmp files have a paired .nef file. Is there a way to execute the command only for those .xmp files that have a similarly named .nef?

Comment: b) Describe 'similarly'. a) For a new question, create a new question. You might then link to this question, pointing out, that it is a similar problem. This should give you much more attention. Note that longer scripts/commands in comments are hardly readable.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh or bash ≥4:

```
for x in **/*.nef; do
  x=${x%.nef}
  if [ -e "$x.xmp" ]; then
    tar -czf "$x.tgz" -- "$x.nef" "$x.xmp" && rm -- "$x.nef" "$x.xmp"
  fi
done
```

Remove the `&& rm …` part if you don't want to delete the archived files.

Remove the `**/` part on the first line to only act in the current directory and not in its subdirectories as well (and then the snippet will work in any shell).

Some old `tar` implementations may not support `-z` to create a gzip archive; then you can use `tar -cf "$x.tar" -- "$x.nef" "$x.xmp" && gzip -o "$x.tgz" -- "$x.tar" && rm …`. If you don't want to delete the files, another possibility is `tar -cf - -- "$x.nef" "$x.xmp" | gzip >"$x.tgz"` (this form can't be combined with `&& rm` because it would delete the source files even if the `tar` command failed).